# Collecting user information for debugging and support

Tags: security, privacy

I have a Java application that I need to support. I'd like it to collect user information, such as system information: OS and hardware for easier diagnostics and support. Are there any security & privacy regulations I need to follow? Do I specifically need consent from the user to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your country and any local regulations, but it is always better accepted to have a privacy policy if you collect sensitive data. You might inform the user upon the first start, for example. You can also explicitly ask the user for a consent and collect only if the user agrees to do it. Informed consent is a nice policy which both informs the user and also asks for a permission. You can then stack the results and release them (if you which and e.g. include it in the policy) stating users provided their consent.